# Get the path of a directory inside a bundle in Symfony

Tags: symfony

From inside a controller I need to get the path of one directory inside a bundle. So I have:

```
class MyController extends Controller{

    public function copyFileAction(){
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $directoryPath = '???'; // /web/bundles/mybundle/myfiles
        $request->files->get('file')->move($directoryPath);

        // ...
    }
}
```

How to get correct `$directoryPath`?

Comment: ./web/bundles/mybundle can be a symlink to the real ./mybundle/ressources/public folder, you may be interested to get this path instead.

Comment: Also I recommend you to set $directoryPath from a parameter with a clean service definition (such an "Uploader" service instead), this is the symfony way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$directoryPath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../web/bundles/mybundle/myfiles';
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code will return this : "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname/app/../web/bundles/mybundle/myfiles"! The ".." will not work!

Comment: @AliBagheriShakib I don't use Windows, but you can probably get around this by using dirname() to replace the '/..': `dirname($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir')) . '/web/bundles/mybundle/myfiles'`

Answer (score 84):

There is a better way to do it:

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->locateResource('@AcmeDemoBundle')
```

will give an absolute path to AcmeDemoBundle

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->locateResource('@AcmeDemoBundle/Resource')
```

will give path to Resource dir inside AcmeDemoBundle, and so on...

InvalidArgumentException will be thrown if such dir/file does not exist.

Also, on a container definition, you can use:

```
my_service:
class: AppBundle\Services\Config
    arguments: ["@=service('kernel').locateResource('@AppBundle/Resources/customers')"]
```

**EDIT**

Your services don't have to depend on **kernel**. There is a default symfony service you can use: **file_locator**. It uses **Kernel::locateResource** internally, but it's easier to double/mock in your tests.

service definition

```
my_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service
    arguments: ['@file_locator']
```

class

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator;

class Service
{  
   private $fileLocator;

   public function __construct(FileLocator $fileLocator) 
   {
     $this->fileLocator = $fileLocator;
   }

   public function doSth()
   {
     $resourcePath = $this->fileLocator->locate('@AppBundle/Resources/some_resource');
   }
}
```

Comment: $this->container->get('kernel')->locateResource('@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js'); Would get you to a path to the js directory under Resources/public - not the 's' for Resources.